# UIButton removeFromSuperview

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, xcode-storyboard

I went through guide from Apple "[Your first iOS app](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/)"

and now I have a button, which is not declared in ViewController:

```
@interface HelloWorldViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
- (IBAction)changeGreeting:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *userName;
@end
```

Now i can remove label (and textField), using [label removeFromSuperview]; but i dont understand how to do it with button. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add an `IBOutlet` to the button as you did for the textfield and the label:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button; // Don't forget to link to this from Interface Builder
// ...
```

Then you can remove the button using:

```
[button removeFromSuperview];
```

---

Also note that the tutorial you linked to says:

> The sender parameter in the action method refers to the object that is sending the action message **(in this tutorial, the sender is the button)**.

So if you want to remove the button when it is tapped (inside `changeGreeting:`), then you don't need the `IBOutlet` because you already have a reference to the button in the `sender` parameter:

```
- (IBAction)changeGreeting:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    // ...
    [button removeFromSuperview];
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the button in the controller like you did as an `IBAction` and this time declare this as an Outlet(`IBoutlet`).. this way you will get its reference in code..

**Alternatively** .. you can set a tag to the button in Interface Builder 
..

and then retrieve in code using `viewWithTag`: method